# Elixir: Loop the actor to rerun itself

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I am making an master-worker application. The Master code is as follows. This code *asynchronously calls workers* in `start_link`. Once the workers are done with their work, they report to master using `handle_cast` asynchronous call. After this I intend keep the master actor **'ON'** so that it can re-spawn the new worker Actors(like it did in first `start_link` call.). However, the master stops once all the worker actors are done with their work. This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364511/proper-elixir-otp-way-to-structure-an-infinite-loop-task) post mentions using recursive call but I am not able to do it with `Genserver`. Is there any method in `Genserver` to achieve it?

```
defmodule Bitcoin.MasterNode do
use GenServer

def start_link(opts) do
    {:ok, pid} = GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__,:ok, opts)
    start_workers(----perform some task asynchronously----)
    {:ok, pid}
end

def set_message(server, name) do
    GenServer.cast(server, {:set_message, name})
end

#callbacks
def init(:ok) do
    names = []
    {:ok, names}
end

def handle_cast({:set_message, name},names) do
    names = names ++ name
    IO.puts name
    {:noreply,names}
end
```

end

**Edit:** I am running application on distributed mode i.e, master is also connected to external worker nodes. If Master dies, the connections also dies out. The intention is to keep the master node with same PID to run infinite times.

Comment: Please don’t use code formatting for emphasis, use emphasis for the emphasis (check my edits to see how.)

Comment: You don't need recursive call to keep a GenServer alive. A GenServer will stay alive until it's explicitly stopped (or it crashes due to error). I don't see any code in your code snippet that would make the GenServer stop. Does `start_workers` stop this GenServer?

Comment: “The intention is to keep the master node with same PID to run infinite times.”—that is impossible. Use named servers instead. Names are not changed with server restarts.

Comment: I am running code using `escript.build` instead of an `iex` shell. The code just stops when the workers are done with their work and there are no more lines left for master to compute. I hope I am able to present my concern.

Comment: @COSTA create a mix application and run it as OTP application, don’t try to hammer nails with a screwdriver. Scripts are to run scripts, which are by default start, do their work and die. Use applications for long-running processes.

Comment: @mudasobwa Unfortunately, My project requires running it using esrcipt.build. I guess I have to change the implementation inside-out. Thanks.

Comment: @mudasobwa Oh yes. I should use named servers. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @COSTA: do worker call any Server method before completing their work. Is `set_message` called by worker at end of their work

Comment: @AnuragPeshne Yes, they invoke servers `Genserver.cast`  i.e, `set_message` before dying.

Comment: I was able to work around the problem by not letting any workers die by calling `start_link()` recursively in worker's `Genserver` code. This is not a proper way though.

Comment: @COSTA: if that is the case, you can spawn new worker from `GenServer.cast` method. So that old worker process is replaced by new and total number of workers remain constant.

Answer (score 2):

If I properly understood your intent, you want to restart the whole process as soon as all children are done. If that’s true, one should use OTP features instead of inventing their own wheels :)

Just extend the supervision tree with one more supervisor, that would be supervising your “master” (`Bitcoin.MasterNode`,) and *you are all set*.

What will happen:

1. `MasterSupervisor` starts;
2. `MasterSupervisor` transparently starts `MasterNode` as a worker with a [`:one_for_one`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#init/2-options) strategy;
3. `MasterNode` acts exactly as it does now;
4. as soon as all workers are done, `MasterNode` *dies*, which is fine;
5. once it’s child `MasterNode` has died, `MasterSupervisor` *will automatically restart it* due to it’s strategy.

---

To keep track of `GenServer` despite whether is was respawned or not, one should use [named servers](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#start_link/3-options) instead of just operating `PID`s:

```
GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__,:ok, name: MyWorker)
```

Comment: My bad. I also want the application to run in distributed mode. If the master dies, external workers will die too.  I have updated the question. Can we still do some elixir-y magic?

Comment: @mudasobwa: I'm new to Erlang (and Elixir) and don't fully understand the concept of supervisors. Shouldn't supervisor restart process if the process *failed*, rather than a successful completion. OP has mentioned in comments that the worker threads invoke `Bitcoin.MasterNode.set_message` before dying, if I were at his place, I would have spawned new process from `set_message` to replace the old process.